# Text problem with workers

Tags: problem-solving

I'm having an entrance examination in two days and I'm having problems with this math problem here.

> A group of workers works on two jobs in two days. The second job is 2 times smaller in volume than the first one. The first day till midday the workers work on the first job, then afternoon half of the group of workers stays at the first job and finishes it, the second group is switching to the second job. The second day one worker from that group finishes the second job while working on it for the whole day. How many workers are there in the group ?

The answer is 8, but I don't know how to get to that answer. If anybody could help me with this problem step by step and if someone could give me some tips and advice on how to approach any text problem. Thank you :D

Comment: Define two variables: $x$ is the number of workers, $y$ is the number of days it takes one worker to finish the first job. Write down two equations representing the given data. Solve this system of two equations in two variables. The answer to your question is the value of variable $x$.

Comment: As I stated above I have an entrance examination in two days and I need to practice all sort of math problems and I am stuck at this one. Believe it or not but my future career depends on this. I'm just asking how to approach it and if you could give me some tips that would be awesome too.

Comment: @barakmanos I still don't know how to set up the equations :(. I'm sorry but hopefully you can help me a little more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x$ denote the number of workers.

Define *working day* as the amount of work done by one worker in one day.

The first job was completed within $x\cdot\frac12+x\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12=\color\red{\frac34x}$ working days.

The second job was completed within $x\cdot\frac12\cdot\frac12+1=\color\green{\frac14x+1}$ working days.

Since the second job is $2$ times smaller than the first job, $\color\red{\frac34x}=2\cdot(\color\green{\frac14x+1})$:

$\frac34x=2\cdot(\frac14x+1)\implies$

$\frac34x=\frac24x+2\implies$

$\frac14x=2\implies$

$x=8$

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I just didn't know how to set up the equation. With your help things have gotten a lot clearer. Thank you again :D

Comment: @Gigaxel: You're welcome :)